# Bug in my php code which reads data from file and keeps log

Tags: php, web

I'm writing some php code and I want to compare an ip address with the ip address the user is coming from.  This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<?php
// set date and hour
$date=date('H:i:s d-m-Y');
// set ip user
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// log text
$ipLog="User entered at " . $date . " from ip address: " . $ip . ".\n";
// write log
$firstLogFile="../../logs/firstLogIP.txt";
// ipcheck
$myfile=fopen("../../logs/ownip.txt", "r") or die("Unable to read ownip file!");
$ownip=fgets($myfile);
fclose($myfile);
if($ip!=$ownip) {
    $handleFirstLog=fopen($firstLogFile, 'a') or die("<br><br>Can't open logfile!<br><br>"); 
    fwrite($handleFirstLog, $ipLog);
    fclose($handleFirstLog);
}
?>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-container">
        <div>
            <?php           
            if($ip!=$ownip) {
                print "ips not equal: " . $ip . " " . $ownip;
            } else {
                print "ips equal";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>

</html>
```

If the ip address of the user don't equals that of the ip address that's stored in my file (../../logs/ownip.txt) then this should be written to logfile (firstLogIP.txt) and you should see "ips not equal" on the screen.

So if the ip's equal, no log should be written and you should see "ips equal" on the screen.

Althoug my ip address and that of the user ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ARE equal, the script still say's "ips not equal" and the ip address is logged!

Any help with this bug?  Thx!!

Comment: can you add var_dump to your code to print the value for the two variables?

Answer (score -1):

try

`if($ip !== $ownip)` {

instead.
explanation: in some scripting languages like php and javascript, there are two string comparison methods: `==` and `===`.
the first is a fast pointer comparison string which is useless in most of the cases, it doesn't really compare the content of the string but rather works only if the two strings came from the very same source.
you better replace all `==` with `===` for string comparisons which does exactly what you expect. you also have `strcmp()` if you need something stronger...

Comment: so maybe maybe also try `if(trim($ip) !== trim($ownip)) {`

Comment: Your explanation of double vs triple equals is way, way off. The double equal sign compares values whereas the triple equals compares values and types e.g. `1 == '1'` is `true` whereas `1 === '1'` is `false`.

Comment: @kiwi: trim() did the job :)